# Count the most common occurrences of a unknown strings in a file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, dns, logfile-analysis

I have a large file full of lines like this...

```
19:54:05 10.10.8.5 [SERVER] Response sent: www.example.com. type A by 192.168.4.5
19:55:10 10.10.8.5 [SERVER] Response sent: ns1.example.com. type A by 192.168.4.5
19:55:23 10.10.8.5 [SERVER] Response sent: ns1.example.com. type A by 192.168.4.5
```

I don't care about any of the other data, only what's after the "response sent:"
I'd like a sorted list of the most common occurrences of the domain-names.
Problem is I won't know all the domain-names in advance, so I can't just do a search for the string.

Using the example above I'd like the output to be along the lines of

```
ns1.example.com (2)
www.example.com (1)
```

...where the number in ( ) is the counts of that occurrence.

How/what could I use to do this on Windows?  The input file is .txt - the output file can be anything.  Ideally a command-line process, but I'm really lost so I'd be happy with anything.

Comment: I _really_ want to help you but I fear your question is not up to the standards of SO. This reads like a gimmi the codez question. Is there _something_ you tried?

Comment: I've tried a few variations of grep command-line options based on other questions I've found on stackoverflow - but honestly coding is not my day job, I was just given this after someone quit - what I've found always wants an input search string (to be known) - so I tried taking the file above, sorting it in excel to remove the extra stuff, then running grep across that for each of the domains, but it's way too slow/manual - I figured there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cat is kinda out of the bag so lets try and help a little. This is a PowerShell solution. If you are having issues with how this works I encourage you to research the individual parts.

If you text file was "D:\temp\test.txt" then you could do something like this.

```
$results = Select-String -Path D:\temp\test.txt -Pattern "(?<=sent: ).+(?= type)" | Select -Expand Matches | Select -Expand Value
$results | Group-Object | Select-Object Name,Count | Sort-Object Count -Descending
```

Using your input you would get this for output

```
Name             Count
----             -----
ns1.example.com.     2
www.example.com.     1
```

Since there is regex I have saved a [link that explains how it works](https://regex101.com/r/vY7tI1/1).

Please keep in mind that SO is, of course, a site that helps programmers and programming enthusiasts. We are devoting our free time where as some people get paid to do this.

Comment: Apparently I'm too young on this site to upvote, but I'd give you all the upvotes I could.  This really helps me out.  I'll admit don't quite understand the nuances of stackoverflow, so I apologize if this was out of line - but I'm in a pinch to solve a DoS problem and this helps immensely.  Thanks again!

Comment: It's OK. Research effort and sample code can go a long way here. Perhaps we shall meet again later. You're welcome

Answer (score 2):

Can you do it in PHP?

```
<?php
$lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

foreach($lines as $value) {
   $arr = explode(' ', $value);
   $domainarr[] = $arr[5];
}

$occurence = array_count_values($domainarr);

print_r($occurence);
?>
```

Comment: Hey Aiken. While this might answer the broad question it's not even one of the languages tagged.

Comment: Hi Matt, tnx for the feedback. OP stated he's happy with anything, and this seemed the best way imho. I'm fairly new to the site, shouldn't I have posted it?

Comment: I'm appreciative regardless - but stupid question time: I'm pretty sure I can setup a php server for this, but I kind of thought that was an exclusively web based language, so do I just put the input.txt file in the same directory as this .php file and reference it (how?), then when I hit the .php page it will process and output the results in the browser?   I would be more intelligent about this if it were .asp or .bat or .ps1 script.

Comment: Indeed, just put them together on a server that has PHP installed, run the file in which you have the PHP-script in the browser, and it will show you what you want.

Answer (score 2):

This is in batch:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if exist temp.txt del temp.txt
for /f "tokens=6" %%a in (input.txt) do (Echo %%a >> temp.txt)
for /f %%a in (temp.txt) do (
set /a count=0
set v=%%a
if "!%%a!" EQU "" (
for /f %%b in ('findstr /L "%%a" "temp.txt"') do set /a count+=1
set %%a=count
Echo !v:~0,-1! ^(!count!^)
)
)
del temp.txt
```

Currently it prints it out to the screen. If you would like to redirect it to a text file replace:

```
Echo !v:~0,-1! ^(!count!^)
```

with:

```
Echo !v:~0,-1! ^(!count!^) >> output.txt
```

This outputted:

```
www.example.com (1)
ns1.example.com (2)
```

With the sample data

Comment: Thanks for this example - it works pretty well, although the output isn't sorted by greatest number of instances first, I can live with that.

Answer (score 2):

This Batch file solution should run faster:

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Accumulate each occurance in its corresponding array element
for /F "tokens=6" %%a in (input.txt) do set /A "count[%%a]+=1"

rem Show the result
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=[]=" %%a in ('set count[') do echo %%a (%%b)
```

Output:

```
ns1.example.com. (2)
www.example.com. (1)
```

To store the result in a file, change the last line by this one:

```
(for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=[]=" %%a in ('set count[') do echo %%a (%%b^)) > output.txt
```